# Errors with running Ruby Government Data SDK Sample

Tags: usa, government, api, programming, labor

I'm trying to the run the ruby version of the program to consume GOV data sources located at : http://usdepartmentoflabor.github.io/Ruby-Sample-App/ .

I get two errors. The first has to do with an incorrect number of arguments being passed in. This is easily rectified by removing the API_SECRET argument.

```
.../dol/GOVDataSDK.rb:24:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (5 for 4)     (ArgumentError)
from GOVDataExample.rb:9:in `new'
from GOVDataExample.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

The second error has to do with the actual constructed URL. It seem to be invalid.

```
$ ruby GOVDataExample.rb
.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:176:in `split': bad URI(is not  URI?): http://api.dol.gov/V1/SummerJobs/getJobsListing?KEY={@context.key}? format='json'&query='farm'&region=&locality=&skipcount=1 (URI::InvalidURIError)
from /Users/sunraa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
from /Users/sunraa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
from /Users/sunraa/Dropbox/Work/epa/teaser/dol/GOVDataSDK.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in call_api'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might try also posting your issues to the code repo that stores this example: https://github.com/USDepartmentofLabor/Ruby-Sample-App

Comment: It looks like the Ruby example you linked to is out of date. You can see that their more recently updated repo has code where the `DataContext` class has a different signature and probably other changes as well. Messy.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had used the DataContext from the repo and tried the included sample. Same results. Will keep digging.

Comment: There has been an update pushed to the [Ruby_DOLDataSDK Github repo](https://github.com/USDepartmentofLabor/Ruby_DOLDataSDK). This should fix the second issue. The "shared secret" has been deprecated and should not be sent; an update will be forthcoming for the sample code. For now just remove that parameter from your sample code file as you have been doing.

Comment: My answer was changed to a comment -- I'm going to take another stab at it -- this issue should be fixed completely now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused by both a bug and a missing update in the Ruby SDK.  It has been fixed now.  You can find the updated Ruby SDK at the [Ruby_DOLDataSDK Github repo](https://github.com/USDepartmentofLabor/Ruby_DOLDataSDK).

Also, the [sample app code](http://usdepartmentoflabor.github.io/Ruby-Sample-App/) you linked has been updated to remove the API_SECRET parameter. The "shared secret" is no longer necessary. So the updated version of the sample program will now work with latest version of the Ruby SDK.